# Active Directory PowerShell script permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm newbie in PowerShell and scripting
I need to write a script that:

1. Lists all GPO's of the domain and checks the list for difference in param "Permission" to be "read" for concrete trustee.
2. If the param "Permission" is for example empty or filled "write" instead of "read", it must change it to "read".

I found a cmdlet in official Microsoft documentation, but it makes only input on console:
`Get-GPPermission -Name "TestGPO" -All`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to check for specific permissions entries in all your GPOs:

```
# put your AD group name here
$target = 'ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS'

# iterate through all GP objects
Foreach ($GPO in (Get-GPO -All)) {
  
  # get current permissions for GPO
  $Current = Get-GPPermission -Name $GPO.DisplayName -TargetName $target -TargetType Group -ErrorAction Ignore

  # check if current permissions exist and are correct
  if ($Current -and ($Current.Permission -eq 'GpoRead')) {
    Write-Host ($GPO.DisplayName + " permissions correct")
  }
  # otherwise, set corrected permissions
  Else {
    Write-Warning ($GPO.DisplayName + " permissions NOT correct")

    # example way to set or add permissions
    #Set-GPPermission -Name $GPO.DisplayName -PermissionLevel GpoRead -TargetName $target -TargetType Group
  }
}

# outputs like
Default Domain Policy permissions correct
Default Domain Controllers Policy permissions correct
Bad-Policy permissions NOT correct
```

However, be aware that all `Authenticated Users` already have Read and Apply access to all GPOs by default, so it may be better to search for Edit permissions and remove them instead (depending on your environment)